# How to have an updating time in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating a calendar app in kivy, and I was wondering how I would be able to add an updating clock? I can use the datetime python function, but when I load it in my app it shows a frozen time with no movement. Suggestions?

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

(Solved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example of how to get this feature working. You should be able to work from this and apply it to your own code. If you have any specific questions, let me know in a comment and I'll be happy to answer :)

```
from kivy.app import App
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.now = datetime.now()

        # Schedule the self.update_clock function to be called once a second
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 1)
        self.my_label = Label(text= self.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        return self.my_label  # The label is the only widget in the interface

    def update_clock(self, *args):
        # Called once a second using the kivy.clock module
        # Add one second to the current time and display it on the label
        self.now = self.now + timedelta(seconds = 1)
        self.my_label.text = self.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I should be able to implement this with my own code. However, I'm a little confused on how I replace your 'my_label' with my ActionLabel in my kivy code?

Comment: @LearningtoCodee Is your entire .kv file just that one ActionLabel widget? And can you edit your code for your .py file to include where you define the ActionLabel class and app class (like 'MyApp' in my example)? I can definitely help

Comment: The ActionLabel is apart of the kivy ActionBar module. Most of my code is in the .kv file. I'll post all of my code

Comment: @LearningtoCodee Since your main app class returns your ManageScreens class, you can use `self.root` to refer to your ManageScreens class from your main app class. To access a widget with an id (your widget you want to update has an id of `time_label`) you use the parent widget's `.id` attribute. Therefore instead of my `self.my_label.text` in my update_clock function, you need to use `self.root.ids['time_label'].text` to make it work for your code

Comment: Personal plug: visit my profile for a link to my youtube channel where i'm making an app from start to finish as part of an intermediate kivy tutorial :)

Comment: Should have been able to figure that out myself lol I have a lot to learn. Could learn a lot from you. Thanks so much.

Comment: It takes a while to pick up, but things start to fit together for sure. Enjoy kivy!

Comment: Rather than adding 1 second on each call to `update_clock()`, wouldn't it be better to just do `self.now = datetime.now()` each time? The `kivy.Clock` times are pretty accurate, but a long running process would accumulate time error.

Comment: True. They both work and I suppose that'd be more logical. Thanks