# Kivy - updating label text periodically

Tags: python, kivy

New to python and kivy. Working on a dashboard to display time and other parameters. Dashboard is currently set and displays all values perfectly. But still can't figure out how to update the time dynamically in those labels used for time. Found similar posts but still struggling. Posting below the summarised portion of my codes.

Worked with the Clock object to trigger a method every one sec which need to update the label text in the kv file. But unable to put this logic into working.

**sample.py**

```
import time
import datetime
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MySec(BoxLayout):
    seconds_string = time.strftime("%S")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Clock.schedule_interval('periodic_method', 1)
        return MySec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv file**

```
<mysec>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: kv_sec
        text: root.seconds_string
        font_size: 200
```

In short, how should I modify the .py file so that so that my .kv label text gets updated every second with the updated value. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: typo: change `<mysec>:` to `<MySec>:`

Comment: Check out this very similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426193/how-to-have-an-updating-time-in-kivy/54426533#54426533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Kivy [`StringProperty`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) to automatically update the `Label`'s text, and use Kivy [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) object e.g. `Clock.schedule_interval()` to update the `StringProperty` at every time interval.

- Replace `seconds_string = time.strftime("%S")` with class attribute of type `StringProperty`, `seconds_string = StringProperty('')`
- Implement a method, `update_time()` to update class attribute, `seconds_string`
- Use Kivy `Clock.schedule_interval()` to invoke method `update_time()`

## [Kivy » Introduction to Properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#introduction-to-properties)

> Properties are an awesome way to define events and bind to them.
>   Essentially, they produce events such that when an attribute of your
>   object changes, all properties that reference that attribute are
>   automatically updated.

## Example

The following example uses `time()` function to extract time. It can be replaced with `datetime.now()` e.g. replace `time.strftime("%S")` with `datetime.now().strftime("%S")`, and add import statement, `from datetime import datetime`

### main.py

```
import time
import kivy

kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


Builder.load_string("""
<MySec>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: kv_sec
        text: root.seconds_string
        font_size: 200
""")


class MySec(BoxLayout):
    seconds_string = StringProperty('')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_time(), 1)
        return MySec()

    def update_time(self):
        self.root.seconds_string = time.strftime("%S")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. It has been such a relief after stumbling through lot of codes. Once again thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome.