# How can I iterate through a string with Kivy?

Tags: python, string, kivy

Normally, in order to print each character one by one in a string I'd do something like:

```
def typing(response):
    for char in response:
        print(char, end = '', flush = True)
        sleep(0.01)
```

How could I do something similar with Kivy if it's possible?

Comment: It's just Python code, so there would be no difference. What errors are you getting when you try?

Comment: Well right now, the only way I know how to print text onto the screen is through the `Label` function like `self.text = Label(text = "Example text")` whereas I'd just use print for python. I'm just learning this so I barely know anything

Comment: `print()` still works in Kivy, but goes to the app logs, not the screen. That doesn't change the answer of looping over a string, though.

Comment: Yeah I'm not too sure how I'm supposed to get it to the screen

Comment: If you want a Label or TextBox to show individual characters of a string, you could separate them by new lines like `text = "\n".join(some_string)`

Comment: You know how in those tv shows or movies on the screen it shows the text being printed as if someone's typing them out? I just kinda want that look but so far I've had no luck

Comment: You'd need to use a timed loop that takes the current label text, then just appends a new character, and resets the label. Again, doesn't change the answer of "looping over a string"

Comment: This might get you started - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56066190/kivy-updating-label-text-periodically

Answer (score 0):

if you use this way in kivy there is no problem but the label is not updated until function complete but you can do this with `Clock` object in kivy for scheduling tasks

Example:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.clock import Clock

from functools import partial

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical")

        self.textinput = TextInput()
        self.root.add_widget(self.textinput)

        self.button = Button(text="animated response!")
        self.button.bind(on_release = self.btnPressed)
        self.root.add_widget(self.button)

        self.animLabel = Label(text="")
        self.root.add_widget(self.animLabel)

        return self.root
    def btnPressed(self, _):
        self.animLabel.text = ""
        if self.textinput.text.strip() != "":
            self.animLabel.text += self.textinput.text[0]
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self._nextCharHandler, self.textinput.text, 1), 0.01)
    def _nextCharHandler(self, text, index, delta):
        try:
            self.animLabel.text += text[index]
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self._nextCharHandler, text, index + 1), 0.01)
        except:
            pass

MainApp().run()
```

Clock docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html